How to Add a Legend to a ggplot with two axes
I've put together this graph and I would like to be able to add a legend to it but can't seem to figure out why it's not showing up and how to easily add it.
data <- data.frame(group = LETTERS[1:5],    # Create example data
                   pol_nb = c(1000, 800, 1200, 900, 800),
                   Prediction = c(0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8),
                   Actual = c(0.5, 1.0, 1.2, 1.5, 0.9))
buffer <- 0.5
scale <- max(data$Prediction)/max(data$pol_nb)
total <- sum(data$pol_nb)

ggplot(data) +
  ### add model fitted prediction
  geom_point(aes(x = group, y = Prediction), group = 1, shape = 21, size = 3, color = "black", fill = "green3") +
  geom_line(aes(x = group, y = Prediction), group = 1, color = "green3") +
  
  ### add actual average
  geom_point(aes(x = group, y = Actual), group = 1, shape = 22, size = 3, color = "black", fill = "purple") +
  geom_line(aes(x = group, y = Actual), group = 1, color = "purple") +
  
  ### add bars
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = pol_nb * buffer * scale), color = "black", fill = "gold", width = 0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Prediction",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./ (buffer * scale * total), 
                        name = 'PoliciesDistribution',
                        labels = scales::label_percent())) +

  theme_light()


I've figured out from this threadif you put the color inside of the aes() that it does appear but not in the way I would expect.

Yes, to get a legend you need to map a value or variable to an aesthetic using aes(). What did you try and how did the output vary from what you want?

I would suggest having a look at long vs wide data formats. {ggplot2} typically expects data in long format, but yours is currently in a wide format: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html That will help you to map a column in the aes() function.

I've added aesthetics to allow you to manually update color schemes to both color and fill aesthetics using the scale_color_manual and scale_fill_manual respectively.
ggplot(data) +
  ### add model fitted prediction
  geom_line(aes(x = group, y = Prediction, color = 'Prediction'), 
            group = 1, color = 'green3') + # hard coded color outside of aes() overrides the color aesthetic but keeps it in the legend
  geom_point(aes(x = group, y = Prediction,color = 'Prediction',fill='Prediction'), 
             group = 1, shape = 21, size = 3) +
  
  ### add actual average
  geom_line(aes(x = group, y = Actual, color = 'Actual'), group = 1, color = 'purple') +
  geom_point(aes(x = group, y = Actual, color = 'Actual', fill = 'Actual'), group = 1, shape = 22, size = 3) +
  
  
  ### add bars
  geom_col(aes(x = group, y = pol_nb * buffer * scale, color = 'Bars', fill = 'Bars'), width = 0.5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Prediction",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./ (buffer * scale * total), 
                        name = 'PoliciesDistribution',
                        labels = scales::label_percent())) +
  
  theme_light() +
  scale_color_manual(name = 'Legend', #Can change legend title here
                     values = c('black','black','black')) +
  scale_fill_manual(name= 'Legend', # must change both title for combined legend
                    values = c('purple','gold','green3'))


